# Swift 2.0 url post request

Tags: ios, swift2

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong whit my code but i keep getting this error in swift 2.0

```
Errors thrown from here are not handled because the enclosing catch is not exhaustive
```

The automated conversion from XCode did a lot of work for me (also gave a LOT of errors) but this is still not working. I don't understand what is working so maybe you guys can throw some light on the case. Thanks in advance

here is my code

```
if config.isConnected() {
        let post:NSString = "postID=\(postID)"
        //NSLog("PostData: %@",post);
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"https://www.example.com/json/index.php")!
        let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
        let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        var reponseError: NSError?
        var response: NSURLResponse?

        var urlData: NSData?
        do {
            urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response) // gives error
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(reponseError)
            reponseError = error
            urlData = nil
        }
        if ( urlData != nil ) {
            Webiew.loadRequest(request)
        } else {
            let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "OOPS", message: "There is nothing here!", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK");
            alert.show()
        }
    } else { 
        // not connected 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code *explained inside *

```
 let parameters = ["userId":"1", "userName":"2"] as Dictionary<String, String>
    //create the url with NSURL
    let url = NSURL(string: "URL") //change the url

    //create the session object
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

    //request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: nil, error: &err) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body

    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setBodyContent(parameters)
    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        // println("Response: \(response)")
        let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("Body: \(strData)")
        let json = try!NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary
        print("account data")
        completion(result: json as NSDictionary?)


        // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
        if(error != nil) {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
        else {
            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            if let parseJSON = json as NSDictionary! {
                // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                _ = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
                //println("Succes: \(success)")
            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                _ = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
               // println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
            }
        }

    })

    task.resume()
```

Add this extension :

```
extension NSMutableURLRequest {
    func setBodyContent(contentMap: Dictionary<String, String>) {
        var firstOneAdded = false
        var contentBodyAsString = String()
        let contentKeys:Array<String> = Array(contentMap.keys)
        for contentKey in contentKeys {
            if(!firstOneAdded) {

                contentBodyAsString = contentBodyAsString + contentKey + "=" + contentMap[contentKey]!
                firstOneAdded = true
            }
            else {
                contentBodyAsString = contentBodyAsString + "&" + contentKey + "=" + contentMap[contentKey]!
            }
        }
        contentBodyAsString = contentBodyAsString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        self.HTTPBody = contentBodyAsString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
}
```

Comment: almost there, there is only one warning i can't get rid off, 
    
contentBodyAsString = contentBodyAsString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

'stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding' is deprecated: Use stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(_:) instead, which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding, and which encodes for a specific URL component or subcomponent since each URL component or subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid.

the proposed solution from xcode does not work

Comment: Same here , for me its working but with the same warning . So i haven't paid too much attention to this . Any chance you can open a new thread about this?

Comment: Its crushing or it dosent even get respond?

Comment: it is working but warnings are never pretty, i will try and find a solution, once i find it i will comment it on here

Comment: Sound great Thomas. Can you please accept my answer? Cheers brorher

Comment: Thomas, found the replacment?

Comment: I used `contentBodyAsString = contentBodyAsString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!`.

Comment: @Webdevotion Awesome . Gonna check it out soon, Thanks

Comment: i get an error on `completion(result: json as NSDictionary?)` that says that completion is unresolved identifier

Comment: @YoavR. Please post new question and attach all the needed info

Comment: @roimulia why?  it is only relevant to this answer... i copied the code from this answer, and got an error - if a fix or a clarification on this code should be made - it should be here....

Comment: @YoavR. I'm not near my computer at this moment. Try delete this line, and fetch the details from the parseJson["success] section(match the "success" with your values

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, i did not need to use the extension you've made.
This way the request is synchronous and it directly gives my response back and i parse it to get the values. It took some searching and trial & error but it is solved :) the code i pasted below is for something else but the principles are the same

```
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: config.versionURL() as String)!)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    var response: NSURLResponse?

    if config.isConnected() {
        var urlData: NSData?
        do {
            urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
        } catch _ {
            urlData = nil
        }
        if ( urlData != nil ) {
            let myJSON = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = myJSON {
                onlineVersion = parseJSON["version"]?.integerValue
                if onlineVersion > prefs.integerForKey("offlineVersion") {
                    showActivityIndicator(self.view)
                    self.structureSetup()
                } else if onlineVersion == prefs.integerForKey("offlineVersion") {
                    if (fileExistance) {
                        let jsonStringData = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: jsonFilePath)
                        fullStructure = JSON(jsonStringData!)
                        numCats = fullStructure["posts"].count
                        self.homeTable.reloadData()
                        hideActivityIndicator(self.view)
                    } else {
                        if config.isConnected() {
                                self.structureSetup()
                        } else {
                            // alert, nothing here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (fileExistance) {
            let jsonStringData = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: jsonFilePath)
            fullStructure = JSON(jsonStringData!)
            numCats = fullStructure["posts"].count
            self.homeTable.reloadData()
        } else {
            if config.isConnected() {
                self.structureSetup()
            } else {
                // alert, nothing here
            }
        }
    }
```