# How to debug network request Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm making a http request to an API with JSON in the body of the request. I know for a fact that my `Dictionary<String, String>` containing the JSON data is correct, still I'm getting a response from the server that my input data is not valid. I'm doing something very similar to this: [Swift 2.0 url post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635147/swift-2-0-url-post-request/33042104#33042104). I even tried the extension suggested there but without success.

how should I debug this? I can't find any way to print my whole request to the console. I want to know what my URLRequest actually contains just before I send the request. Also, I want to know that this hex gibberish is actually the right gibberish I meant it to be, how should I do this?

Comment: follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34705449/4600952

Answer (score 13):

Nothing special about that? Just write an extension and print whatever you want

example:

```
extension Data {
    func toString() -> String? {
        return String(data: self, encoding: .utf8)
    } 
}

extension URLRequest {
    func log() {
        print("\(httpMethod ?? "") \(self)")
        print("BODY \n \(httpBody?.toString())")
        print("HEADERS \n \(allHTTPHeaderFields)")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
request.log()
```

Sample log:

```
POST https://httpbin.org/
BODY 
Optional("password=xxx&username=xxx")
HEADERS 
Optional(["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"])
```