# how to print http request to console

Tags: swift

Is it possible to print the whole http(s) request just before doing the actual request?

This is my code:

```
let postsEndpoint: String = "https://www.example.com/api/"
guard let postsURL = NSURL(string: postsEndpoint) else {
    throw APICallError.other("cannot create URL")
}
let postsURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: postsURL)
postsURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
print(UTF8EncodedJSON)
postsURLRequest.HTTPBody = UTF8EncodedJSON
print(postsURLRequest) 

let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(postsURLRequest, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in
    //handle response
})
```

this prints the json in hex first and then:

`<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7fdae8d1dd30> { URL: https://www.ritzie.nl/api/v2 }`

which doesn't help me much. I just want to have my whole request printed like you would see it in firebug on firefox for example.

*--edit--*

To clarify, I'm not trying to print my json. There's enough questions about that on SO already. I want my full request printed out something like this:

```
POST /api/v2/ HTTP/1.1

HTTP headers:
Host: www.example.ocm
Origin: http://www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/\*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9
Referer: http://www.ritzie.nl/api/test.php
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

request body:
data=%7B%22action%22%3A+%22vehicleRecords%22%2C%0D%0A%22token%22%3A+%22token_04e01fdc78205f0f6542bd523519e12fd3329ba9%22%2C%0D%0A%22vehicle%22%3A+%22vehicle_e5b79b2e%22%7D
```

or this:

[image: Firebug request screenshot]

Comment: If you want to see the JSON text you need to create a string from the data is all

Comment: @Wain, lol no, I want to see my whole http request. Like this:
`GET /api/v2/ HTTP/1.1

HTTP headers:
Host: www.ritzie.nl
Accept: */*
Cookie: PHPSESSID=vd61qutdll216hbs3a677fgsq4
User-Agent: KM%20registratie%20tabbed%20NL/1 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.2.0
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: So you need to print the headers yourself

Comment: yea, so, how do I do this?

Comment: Surely you don't want that logged all the time. Best is to use a proxy tool as that tells you what truly hits the network

Comment: tried that too.. Everyones recommending Charles but that's not working for me. I installed the ssh certificate in the simulator but it still doesn't trust the connection...

Comment: Then the certificate isn't installed properly or you have written certificate pinning logic in your code

Comment: well I'm using the built-in install certificate to iOS simulators function and had supposed that'd do what it's supposed to do. I don't know how to pin certificates so I don't think I'm doing that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In **Swift 5**:

```swift
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
  print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
}
```

If you are trying to see the whole HTTP request:

```swift
print("\(request.httpMethod!) \(request.url!)")
print(request.allHTTPHeaderFields!)
print(String(data: request.httpBody ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8)!)
```

You can add this last bit into an extension:

```swift
fileprivate extension URLRequest {
    func debug() {
        print("\(self.httpMethod!) \(self.url!)")
        print("Headers:")
        print(self.allHTTPHeaderFields!)
        print("Body:")
        print(String(data: self.httpBody ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8)!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
print("\(URLRequest.httpMethod ?? "") \(URLRequest.url)")
let str = String(decoding: URLRequest.httpBody!, as: UTF8.self)
print("BODY \n \(str)")
print("HEADERS \n \(URLRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields)")
```

Answer (score 4):

Print it inside the completionHandler :

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(postsURLRequest) {
    data, response, error in
    //handle response
     print(NSString(data: data.HTTPBody!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
}
```

if it didn't work then use the following :

```
print(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

Comment: you're printing the response body, I want the whole request

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me :

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(postsURLRequest) { data, response, error in
    if let data {
        do {
            var jsonResult: NSDictionary
            try jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            print("AsSynchronous\(jsonResult)")
        }
        catch {
            // handle error
        }
    } else {
        print("Error: no data for request \(urlPath)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(postsURLRequest) {
    data, response, error in
    //handle response
     print(NSString(data: response.request, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
}
```

Comment: There is no request property on the response object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CustomStringConvertible or CustomDebugStringConvertible for generating descriptions on URLRequest extension. You can include the properties you want in return string.

```
extension URLRequest /*: CustomStringConvertible*/{
    public var description: String{
        get{
            return "HEADERS \n \(String(describing: allHTTPHeaderFields))"
        }
    }
}

Use : print(<session task>.currentRequest?.description)
```